# asp.net localize text from files in \bin folder files

Tags: vb.net, resources, localization, globalization

Im struggling with gettings the values from the right strings.txt in my resource files in my \bin folder when switching languages.

[default.aspx.vb]

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Shared rm As ResourceManager = HttpContext.Current.Application("RM")

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Label.Text = rm.GetString("homewelcome") '"Alles over trouwen, voor je perfecte bruiloft"
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        SetLanguage(Request.Url.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub SetLanguage(ByVal URL As String)
        Dim lang As String = ""
        If URL.Contains("www.domain.nl") Then
            lang = "nl"
        ElseIf URL.Contains("www.domain.com") Then
            lang = "en"
        End If
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang)
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[global.asax]

```
    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Application("RM") = New ResourceManager("strings", Assembly.Load("strings"))
    End Sub
```

In my bin folder I have:

bin\strings.txt
bin\nl\strings.nl.txt
bin\en\strings.en.txt

I generate the dlls like so:

```
resgen strings.txt strings.resources
al /embed:strings.resources,strings.resources /out:strings.dll
resgen nl\strings.nl.resources
al /embed:nl\strings.nl.resources,strings.nl.resources /out:nl\strings.resources.dll /c:nl
resgen en\strings.en.resources
al /embed:en\strings.en.resources,strings.en.resources /out:en\strings.resources.dll /c:en
```

Now, all files seem to be created correctly.

However, when I go to the www.domain.com, the values in bin\strings.txt are used and NOT (like I would expect and desire), the values from bin\en\strings.en.txt

Why?

Comment: Curious ... does www.domain.nl work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code snippet on a .NET 4.0 Windows 2008 computer.  It worked as you are wanting it to.

The only thing I could think of ...  the computer I tried it on had the Windows MUI installed.   Wondering if that is a factor?

Comment: Im running on Windows 7 and have only the English language on here, so I would expect that part to work at least. I debugged a little more and found that in mu InitializeCulture method:     Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        SetLanguage(Request.Url.ToString)
    End Sub
When I check for the current System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString its equal to "en", so it seems that the culture is SET correctly, its only that not the correct strings.dll is used....does that help in helping me further? :)

Comment: But there's more strange things going on:

Also I have this in my default.aspx
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:lookingfor%>" /> 

When I approach www.domain.com, the Literal1 controls displays the value from "App_LocalResources\default.aspx.en.resx" 

And when I check the current System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString its equal to "en", so it seems that the culture is SET correctly.

So when using www.domain.com, the WRONG strings.dll is used, but the CORRECT .resx file...seems a bit too inconsistent to me!